# Как мне анимировать prepend?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу чтобы не сразу появлялся prepand, а немного анимировано: появлялся не так быстро и справа налево.

Вот моя реализация:

```js
$('.client').hover(function() {
    $(this).prepend('<div class="remove">Remove</div>').show('fast')
  },
  function() {
    $('.remove').remove();
  });

$('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
})
```

```css
.panel {
  margin: 10px;
}

.remove {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
<div class="row executer-index panel">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 client">
    <div>
      <div class="caption">
        <p>Фамилия имя: Иванов Иван</p>
        <p>Телефон: +7911111233</p>
        <p>email: test@mail.ru</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 client">
    <div>
      <div class="caption">
        <p>Фамилия имя: Иванов Иван</p>
        <p>Телефон: +7911111233</p>
        <p>email: test@mail.ru</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 client">
    <div>
      <div class="caption">
        <p>Фамилия имя: Иванов Иван</p>
        <p>Телефон: +7911111233</p>
        <p>email: test@mail.ru</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

То есть мне нужен вот этот код преобразовать `$(this).prepend('<div class="remove">Remove</div>').show('fast')`

Comment: Можно CSSом сделать

Comment: Куча кода ради одного hover)))))

Comment: @Air А какой есть более короткий способ?

Comment: `css :hover`, намного проще...  Если конечно  не принципиально, чтобы данный элемент `div class="remove` не создавался и не удалялся каждый раз

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет смысла всякий раз при `hover` создавать элемент и анимировать его JS-ом. Если не хочется лопатить разметку, можно `.remove` просто добавить в блоки по готовности документа, а дальше `css` сделает своё.

```js
$('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
})
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  margin:0;
}
.panel {
  margin: 10px;
}
.client{
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.caption{
  padding-right:80px;
}
.client .remove{
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  right:-50px;
  top:30px;
  cursor:pointer;
  opacity:0;
  transition:all .3s ease;
}
.client:hover .remove{
  right:10px;
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
<div class="row executer-index panel">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 client">
      <div class="caption">
        <p>Фамилия имя: Иванов Иван</p>
        <p>Телефон: +7911111233</p>
        <p>email: test@mail.ru</p>
      </div>
      <span class="remove">remove</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 client">
      <div class="caption">
        <p>Фамилия имя: Иванов Иван</p>
        <p>Телефон: +7911111233</p>
        <p>email: test@mail.ru</p>        
      </div>
      <span class="remove">remove</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 client">
      <div class="caption">
        <p>Фамилия имя: Иванов Иван</p>
        <p>Телефон: +7911111233</p>
        <p>email: test@mail.ru</p>
      </div>
      <span class="remove">remove</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы делаете `show` видимого элемента с классом `client` после `prepend`. Почитайте как работает chaining.

Вместо этого я бы вставлял спрятанный элемент перед текущим , а затем его показывал.

```js
$('.client').hover(function() {
    $(this).prepend('<div class="remove" style="display:none">Remove</div>');
    $('.remove').show('fast');
  },
  function() {
    $('.remove').remove();
  });

$('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
})
```

```css
.panel {
  margin: 10px;
}

.remove {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
<div class="row executer-index panel">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 client">
    <div>
      <div class="caption">
        <p>Фамилия имя: Иванов Иван</p>
        <p>Телефон: +7911111233</p>
        <p>email: test@mail.ru</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 client">
    <div>
      <div class="caption">
        <p>Фамилия имя: Иванов Иван</p>
        <p>Телефон: +7911111233</p>
        <p>email: test@mail.ru</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 client">
    <div>
      <div class="caption">
        <p>Фамилия имя: Иванов Иван</p>
        <p>Телефон: +7911111233</p>
        <p>email: test@mail.ru</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74425/discussion-on-answer-by-yolosora----prepend).